# How to Use sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment on linux server?

Tags: java, swing, awt, screenshot, x11

I am using AWS linux server but i get error like :  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment

I take a screenshot using java.awt.robot class

Here is my code :

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO; public class DesktopScreenshot {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        Rectangle screenShot = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        BufferedImage screenFullImage = robot.createScreenCapture(screenShot);
        File screenshotFile = new File("screenshot.png");
        ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, "png", screenshotFile);
    }
}
```

Set headless Property :  System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false")
then i get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment

and when i set this Property this to true it gives "headless environment exception"

Here i try some solution :

set environment Variable : -Djava.awt.headless=false

Install X11 server on linux server and add dependencies

set DISPLAY variable : export DISPLAY=0.0 and also try export DISPLAY=0.0 and also unser Display varible

Also add dependency and library for sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment

Nothing works out.

Anybody has solution or knowledge about this problem?

Comment: check your jdk is headless or full ?

Comment: jdk installation is full not a headless.

Comment: (0)  Test Environment: `Ubuntu 20.04` , JDK: `OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.6+10 (build 17.0.6+10)` , IDE: IDEA `IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2 (Community Edition)`
(1) Run your code: WORK, get screenshot.png (2) Run your code with  `System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");` , WORK, get creenshot.png (3) Run your code with  `System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");` , get ERROR  `Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTException: headless environment` YES, Beacuse I set `headless`is `true`, (4)  I can't reproduce your error, on my environment.

Comment: If set `System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");` , will get `Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTException: headless environment` , NOT  YOUR EXCEPTION`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment`

Comment: Now i am getting error like :
 Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable

Comment: I guess you should first confirm whether your AWS Server has a GUI (Desktop) installed?

Comment: Desktop is not installed.

Comment: You must install the Linux GUI `xorg` libraries. then add `-Djava.awt.headless=true`

Comment: -Djava.awt.headless=true gives java.awt.AWTException: headless environment exception.

Comment: then REMOVE this `-Djava.awt.headless=true`